# spring-integration 5.5.18 messaging-gateway timeouts

Tags: spring-mvc, timeout, spring-integration

I'm using `@MessagingGateway` in order to bridge between `spring-mvc` `@Controller` and `spring-integration`.  The `@MessagingGateway` declaration looks like this:

```
package a.b.c;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@MessagingGateway(name="inboundGateway" defaultRequestTimeout="2000"
                                        defaultReplyTimeout="2000")

@Component
public interace InboundGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "getSomething")
    Message<SomeValue> getSomething(@Headers Map<String, Object> headers);

}
```

which is referenced from a Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/some/base/path")
public class SomeController {

    private final InboundGateway inboundGateway;

    public SomeController(InboundGateway inboundGateway) {
        this.inboundGateway = inboundGateway;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "things", produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<SomeValue> getSomething(RequestContext<String> requestContext) {
        Message<SomeValue> response = inboundGateway.getSomething(requestContext);
        ....
}
```

I was thinking that the definitions of `defaultRequestTimeout` and `defaultReplyTimeout` would raise a timeout at the `inboundGateway` if the response was not returned within the specified time.

However, I'm seeing instead that the time used within the method `getSomething()` can surpass the specified time, in this example, 2 seconds.  It seems that the 2 seconds is used as a timeout for the calls to downstream systems, but not as a timeout for the return from `getSomething()`.

Am I understanding this correctly?  Is there some simple, declarative way of managing the timeout at the `inboundGateway` level?  Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you explaining is typical for flows where your `inboundGateway` is a `DirectChannel`. This way the message process is performed directly on the thread producing that message. So, it cannot reach the `replyTimeout` for result since that thread is blocked waiting for message handling.

See more info in docs for different channels: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/implementations.html

Also see docs for those timeouts on the Gateway: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/gateway.html

As a simple solution for your expectation you may consider to use a `QueueChnanel` for that `inboundGateway` or an `ExecutorChannel`. This way the processing will be handed off to a different thread and gateway will be able easily move on to the reply waiting block. And that's where that `replyTimeout` will have an effect.

It is also explained in that annotation attribute JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Provides the amount of time dispatcher would wait to send a {@code Message}. This
 * timeout would only apply if there is a potential to block in the send call. For
 * example if this gateway is hooked up to a {@code QueueChannel}. Value is specified
 * in milliseconds; it can be a simple long value or a SpEL expression; array variable
 * #args is available.
 * See {@link Gateway#requestTimeout()} for per-method configuration.
 * @return the suggested timeout in milliseconds, if any
 */
String defaultRequestTimeout() default IntegrationContextUtils.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_STRING;
```

Comment: That does seem to do the trick.  After changing from ```DirectChannel``` to ```QueueChannel```, the return from the call to the gateway is ```null```.  Should I consider that a ```null`` is always a ```timeout``` or is there some way of checking this and perhaps getting some additional information for forming an error response?

Comment: Yeah... We have introduced such an `errorOnTimeout` option in the latest `6.2` version: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/gateway.html#long-running-process-downstream

Comment: Looks like what I need is to set ```errorOnTimeout``` in the MessagingGateway .. but I'm not seeing how to add that from the ```@MessagingGateway``` annotation.

Comment: I just said you: it is available since Spring Integration `6.2`. Your one is too old to have that option.

Comment: OK, I understand that it's not available from ```@MessagingGateway``` annotation in 5.5.18, and I'm stuck with that older version for the moment.  Is there a way to set this via a ```BeanPostProcessor``` or similar?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. you need to track `GatewayProxyFactoryBean` beans from there and call its `getGateways()`. Iterate through values and call `MessagingGatewaySupport.setErrorOnTimeout(true)`.